# bitwise meaning in createparams class

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, createparams

I'm trying to understand the meaning of each bit in the createparams class.
i tried to find any information about it, even in msdn web site, but nowhere explains the meaning for the bits.
Does someone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says

> The constants used to set the Style, ExStyle, and ClassStyle properties are defined in the Winuser.h header file. This file is installed by the Platform SDK or Visual Studio.

so find `winuser.h` on your system and have a look!